# Half loaded images on AWS

Tags: node.js, browser, amazon-web-services, nginx, express

**Update** It may have something to do with nginx being in front of node. Awsbox does this for you, but I'm really unfamiliar with it. Why would nginx halt image loading during the request response? (I've tested to make sure this isn't a browser thing)

I'm getting a really weird behavior that I don't know how to track down.

I'm using awsbox to deploy node.js (express) apps on ec2 instances in AWS. The quick tutorial went almost perfectly smooth. Here's the hang up. When I load my site: 54.196.4.102 the site loading hangs for a couple minutes, and just a few of the images appear half loaded (the bottom 3/4 of the images don't show).

I ssh'ed in and manually updated the images in question, at which point sometimes the images load just fine sometimes they don't. If I hit f5 to refresh everything is peachy. If I hit ctrl + shift + R I get the old half-loaded images. Weird! What the heck is goin' on inside you, virtual machine!

Any help would rock : )